# When to use this for class function in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, this

When should `this` be used in a lambda to call a class member function? I have an example below, where `hello();` is called without `this` but `this->goodbye();` does:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{   
    void hello() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }
    void goodbye() { std::cout << "goodbye" << std::endl; }

public:  
    void greet()
    {   
        auto hi = [this] () { hello(); }; // Don't need this.
        auto bye = [this] () { this->goodbye(); }; // Using this.

        hi();
        bye();
    }   
};  


int main()
{   
    A a;
    a.greet();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any advantage to one way over the other?

Edit: The lambda for `hello` does not capture anything, yet it inherits functions that exist in the class scope. It cannot do this for members, why can it do this for functions?

Answer (score 2):

`this` is more explicit and more verbose.

but it might be also required with variables which hide member (capture or argument):

```
auto goodbye = [](){}; // Hide method
auto bye = [=] (int hello) {
    this->goodbye(); // call method
    goodbye(); // call above lambda.
    this->hello(); // call method
    std::cout << 2 * hello; // show int parameter.
};
```

Comment: Note that these are the same rules as outside a lambda.

Comment: But the lambda does not capture anything, yet it inherits functions that exist in the class scope. It cannot do this for members, why can it do this for functions?

Comment: lambda `goodbye` doesn't capture anything, but `bye` does, it captures `this` and lambda `goodbye`.